# Nested lambda expressions in python map and reduce

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, slice, reduce

My code currently contains, as part of the condition for a while loop:

`reduce(operator.or_, map(lambda y: reduce(operator.or_, map(lambda x: x[0] == y, data[testedoffset:])), footers))`

It's purpose is to check if a given slice of a python array.array instance contains one of several specific byte values.

The error I'm getting is:

`NameError: global name 'y' is not defined`

So I'm pretty sure it's a scoping issue.  But I can't think of a way to do what I want from here.

Comment: Wow, that expression frightens me. Who is going to understand that? Even you can't seem to tell if it's doing what you want. Take others' advice and rewrite it more intelligibly.

Comment: If you want to provide an answer to your question, please post it as an _answer_ , don't obliterate your question which makes every other answer that you received 'out of context noise'.

Comment: Noted, but I didn't "obliterate" my question, I simply added a header stating that the question was invalid, and my issue was not with the code posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you found the answer on your own, but while you're here... 
That code really could use some work.

I'm not entirely sure why you're mapping that expression based on `data[testedoffset:]` across the `footers` sequence. That doesn't seem to have any effect whatsoever, unless your `__getitem__` has side effects.

But the whole `map + reduce + operator.or_` thing gives me the willies.

Try something more like this:

```
y = 'whatever'
if any(x[0] == y for x in data[offset:]):
    print "yep, it's in there"
```

Comment: On second thought, I do understand what the footers thing is doing. You can write it like this: `any(x[0] == y for x in data[offset:] for y in footers)`

Comment: Well, I can't do what you suggested because the expression is a condition for a while loop.  But thank you for the help.

Comment: What? :) Sure you can. Ignore the if statement. Just replace your condition with the any(...) expression. It'll work. I promise. :)

Comment: so like:  `any(any(x == y[0] for x in data[offset:]) for y in footers)`  Interesting!  I'll remember that for in the future.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Yep. That works too... But see my first comment above for an even simpler version. These (expression for x in series) things are called generator comprehensions, and you can have any number of 'for' or even 'if' clauses in them.

Comment: Using generators is also far preferred to using operators, lambdas, map, and reduce.

Answer (score 0):

That sure is not a scoping issue and it is clearly an **unpythonic** expression.
Here is my attempt to understand it and I find that you have to passing y to the lambda expression.

```
reduce(operator.or_,
       map(lambda y: reduce(operator.or_, map(lambda x: x[0] == y, data[testedoffset:]))
                ,#Where is y
           , footers))
```

Comment: Actually, I failed at reading line numbers, my issue was a little farther down the script where I had another lambda with a y in it improperly.

Comment: Even for this expression, for `lambda y:` map function, where are you sending `y`, I understand that `footers` is the outer level reduce.

Comment: `lambda x: x[0] == y`  is where it's being used.  footers is for the outer map, not the outer reduce.

Comment: Senthil, the y in the inner lambda comes from the outer lambda. But you're right. This is very unpythonic code. :)

Comment: Okay got it. footers is for the outer map. Thanks for pointing that out.